# Multiple step powershell command

Tags: windows, powershell, syntax, parameter-passing

I have a windows task that executes a powershell command once a time at 1:15AM

Currently, they operation works using this command

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell/Operational | Export-CSV C:\temp\Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell-Operational.csv
```

Problem is - the file gets written over each time it is executed.

I would like to use a filename of the date it was run.

Interactively, I have this code block and it works

```
$filenameFormat = "c:\temp\" + (Get-Date -Format "MM_dd_yyyy") + "_MWPSO.csv"
Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell/Operational | Export-CSV #filenameFormat
```

I've tried these commands

```
# Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell/Operational | Export-CSV "c:\temp\" + (Get-Date -Format "MM_dd_yyyy") + "_MWPSO.csv"

# $filenameFormat = "c:\temp\" + (Get-Date -Format "MM_dd_yyyy") + "_MWPSO.csv" ` Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell/Operational | Export-CSV $filenameFormat

# $filenameFormat = "c:\temp\" + (Get-Date -Format "MM_dd_yyyy") + "_MWPSO.csv"
# Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell/Operational | Export-CSV  $filenameFormat
```

Question :  How do I use the newly created filename in a **SINGLE** line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I use the newly created filename in a SINGLE line of code?

You're already doing it in:

```
.. | Export-CSV "c:\temp\" + (Get-Date -Format "MM_dd_yyyy") + "_MWPSO.csv"
```

Just missing parentheses so the concatenation is evaluated first:

```
.. | Export-CSV ("c:\temp\" + (Get-Date -Format "MM_dd_yyyy") + "_MWPSO.csv")
```

Alternatively you can use [`$(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3#subexpression-operator--) for string interpolation:

```
.. | Export-Csv "C:\temp\$((Get-Date -Format 'MM_dd_yyyy'))_MWPSO.csv"
```